# This is for right braces... Want help for the left one

Tags: brackets

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{picture}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Here is text}
  \begin{itemize}[<+->]
  \item A first item
  \item Another item, also inside the brace 
        \makebox(0,0){\put(0,2.2\normalbaselineskip){%
               $\left.\rule{0pt}{1.1\normalbaselineskip}\right\}$ foo}}
  \item Outside the brace
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you want here. Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 4):

I am not really sure what you effect you are trying to achieve but perhaps it is something like this:

[image]

The main problem is that you need to move the text on other items lines that are affected to make room for the left brace and its' text. To automate this would, I think, be quite involved so I have manually moved the text using `\hspace*{}`.

Apart from this, the code is pretty much the same as what you have for the right-hand brace except that I have made macros `\LeftBrace{text}` and `\RightBrace{text}` for doing this. By default they both span two lines but, as in my example, you can change this with an optional argument. Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{picture}
\newcommand\RightBrace[2][1.1]{\makebox(0,0){\put(0,2.2\normalbaselineskip){%
               $\left.\rule{0pt}{#1\normalbaselineskip}\right\}$ #2}}}

\newcommand\LeftBrace[2][1.1]{\makebox(0,0){\put(0,2.2\normalbaselineskip){#2%
$\left\{\rule{0pt}{#1\normalbaselineskip}\right.$}}\phantom{#2\{}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Here is text}
  \begin{itemize}[<+->]
  \item A first item
  \item Another item, also inside the brace\RightBrace{foo}
  \item Outside the brace
  \item \hspace*{9mm}Inside the left brace
  \item \LeftBrace[2]{goo} Inside the brace
  \item \hspace*{9mm}Inside the left brace
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{picture}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Here is text}
  \begin{itemize}[<+->]
  \item A first item
  \item Another item, also inside the brace 
        \makebox(0,0){\put(0,2.2\normalbaselineskip){%
               $\left\{\rule{0pt}{1.1\normalbaselineskip}\right.$ foo}}
  \item Outside the brace
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using [tikz](/questions/tagged/tikz) and a tweaked [tikzmark](/questions/tagged/tikzmark), which spans over the line height by using a vertical `\strut`, so you have anchor points at a litte below the baseline and at the top of the line.

Tikz allows you to tweak the brace indiviudally.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{picture}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

% flexible textmark with anchorpoints regarding a strut inline
\newcommand{\tikzmarkflex}[1]{\tikz[remember picture]\node[inner sep = 0pt](#1){\vphantom{\strut}};\relax}%

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Here is text}
  \begin{itemize}[<+->]
  \item A first item
  \item Another item, also inside the brace
  \item Outside the brace
  \item \parbox{1cm}{\hfill\tikzmarkflex{A}} Inside the left brace
  \item \parbox{1cm}{\hfill} Inside the brace
  \item \parbox{1cm}{\hfill\tikzmarkflex{B}} Inside the left brace
  \end{itemize}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture, shift={(current page.south west)}]
            \draw[decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=5pt},line width = 1pt] (B.south west) -- (A.north west)
                 node [midway,xshift=-0.7cm,align=right] {C};
  \end{tikzpicture}%


\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

It requires a double compilation as it works with overlays.

[image]